# limited enter chars and prevent user to type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I want the user to enter a maximum of 5 lines in textarea with a maximum 15 chars in each line.  After that user should be able to prevent press any keys except Arrows, Del, Backspace etc.

Here is my function which accepts TextareaId, event and limit of each textarea (I'm having 3 textareas with different char limit), I'm reaching to `event.preventDefault();` in code but it still allow user to add more chars

```
function charCountTextarea(textAreaId,event,limit)
{
  var code = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
  var Length = $("#"+textAreaId).val().length;
  var t = $("#"+textAreaId)[0];
  var AmountLeft = limit - Length;
  var lineIndex = t.value.substr(0, t.selectionStart).split("\n").length-1;
  var t = $("#"+textAreaId).val().split("\n");
  var lineIndex = (t.length)-1

  var controlKeys = [8, 46, 37, 38,39,40];
  var isControlKey = controlKeys.join(",").match(new RegExp(event.which));

  if(lineIndex>4 && t[lineIndex].length>15) {
    if(isControlKey) {
      return;
    }
    else {
      console.log("prevent");
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  if(AmountLeft<0) {
    if(isControlKey) {
      return;
    }
    else {
      console.log("preve 2");
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
var characters=500 //max characters

$("#MyTextArea").keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val().length > characters){
        $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, characters));
    }
});
```

or in you code, instead

```
event.preventDefault()
```

to use:

```
$(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, characters));
```

Comment: either $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, characters)); is not working Joro, by the way thanks to ping me

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use javascript, you can simply limit with 'maxlength' attribute:

```
<textarea name="hard" maxlength='45'></textarea>
```

Comment: maxlength will work only for char limit, i need max 5 lines in textarea and max 15 chars in each line.

Comment: Also, this is HTML5, and not necessarily implemented by all browser (in particular IE)